# Se requiere una referencia de objeto para el campo en c#

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, xml

hoy tengo un problema que creo que deben ser las referencias la cuestion es que me manda el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

yo tengo mi class AESCrypto.cs

y aqui esta la párte del codigo que marca error

```
namespace _TNS
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           



 
string originalString = "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";
            string key = "5DCC67393750523CD165F17E1EFADD21";
            string decryptedString = AESCrypto.decrypt(key, originalString);
            Console.Write(decryptedString);


        }
    }
}
```

y asi es como se ve mi class AESCrypto.cs

METODO deSCRYPT
agrego el codigo el cual permite ejecutar la desencriptacion del codigo
para poder procesar sus demas argumentos

public string decrypt(string strKey, string strToDecrypt)
{
try
{
string original = strToDecrypt;

```
            // Create a new instance of the Aes
            // class.  This generates a new key and initialization 
            // vector (IV).
            using (Aes myAes = Aes.Create())
            {
                myAes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                myAes.KeySize = 128;
                myAes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                myAes.BlockSize = 128;
                myAes.FeedbackSize = 128;
                byte[] key = new byte[] { };
                byte[] xmlByte = new byte[] { };
                String result = "";

                string str = strKey;
                key = StringToByteArray(str);

                var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(strToDecrypt);
                byte[] IVAES128 = new byte[16];
                Array.Copy(base64EncodedBytes, 0, IVAES128, 0, 16);
                myAes.IV = IVAES128;

                base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(strToDecrypt);
                xmlByte = new byte[base64EncodedBytes.Length - 16];
                Array.Copy(base64EncodedBytes, 16, xmlByte, 0, base64EncodedBytes.Length - 16);
                myAes.Key = key;

                // Encrypt the string to an array of bytes.
                result = DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes128(xmlByte, myAes.Key, myAes.IV);
                return result;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Message);
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te pasa eso porque la clase no la declaras como **estática**. Debes instanciarla haciendo:

```
MiClase obj = new MiClase();
obj.MiMetodo();
```

Cuando una **clase es estática** los miembros pertenecen a la **clase**, son comunes a todos los **objetos** de la **clase**.

Cuando una **clase no es estática** los miembros solo le pertenecen a su **instancia**, es decir son individuales, por lo que una **instancia** puede tener determinado valor en una propiedad y otra **instancia** un valor diferente.

Comment: entonces lo pongo asi             AESCrypto decrypt = new AESCrypto(); lo deje asi pero no me quito el error

Comment: lo añadi de esa forma pero aun me dice el error  de se requiere una referencia

Comment: Ahora lo que tienes que hacer después de construir el objeto, llamar al método desde la instancia, AesCripto x = new AesCripto(); y después x.decrypt(key, originalString); @RobertMendoza

Comment: @RobertMendoza, ya no te hace falta poner AesCripto.decrypt(key, originalString);

Comment: lo quite y me marco que no se puede convertir el tipo string

Comment: @RobertMendoza, a mi lo que me parece es que tienes otros errores que no tienen nada que ver con el tratamos aqui

Comment: @RobertMendoza, edita tu pregunta y pon el codigo del método decrypt, que es el que te interesa y no hablas nada de el

Comment: claro hay la pongo

Comment: ya lo agrege dentro

Comment: ya lo corregi al parecer no me arrojo error alguno -->    string originalString = oPincgMZq/Bhp/XJ0kd70RX1H67nx6ZZj/5oBH8COyr4w9ZOriIXzOfHxCP+ge9jxKH8lw+LqIx/sgvdUW+lCBv1eVYj3v4uyqWkIVsDHr4vNse24g56mXC2Uz6GHF/1OLldn/EIS1uELP2u5brUbYyw/pVG4c8WdzQuKoMJkMq1SNrx5sFTur5DaNsJXsXHwuvhK/aVuyDE92qbXHmQPohDs8p+4o3lSp1RshnqRrGL1xs9BzhtksFVkcYU7g==";
            string key = "5DCC67393750523CD165F17E1EFADD21";
           

            AESCrypto Encripta = new AESCrypto();


            string decryptedString = Encripta.decrypt(key, originalString);
            Console.Write(decryptedString);

Comment: @RobertMendoza, que bueno q resolviste, si consideras mi respuesta util, marcala como aceptada, y si tambien lo deseas dale un voto, gracias!!

Comment: si gracias muy amable

Comment: @RobertMendoza, para marcar una respuesta como aceptada lee esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: a yap es que la marque con el logo asia arriba como me gusta jeje pero ya le di palomita